# Explicitly specify generic type constraint when calling function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am wondering wether or not is possible in `Swift` to explicitly specify the generic type of a generic function. Assuming I have the following function definition which basically creates an empty array of a generic type `T`:

```
func bar<T>() -> [T] {
    return [T]()
}
```

How would I be able to call it?

```
var foo = bar()
```

results in

> generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

which makes total sense since there really is no information to infer anything here.

But unfortunately my attempt at specifying the type constraint explicitly via the following failed as well:

```
var foo = bar<Int>()
```

> error: cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

- Why am I not able to do that?
- Is it a language specification to not be able to explicitly specify the generic type?
- What way is there to specify the generic type of the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What way is there to specify the generic type of the function?

The generic type can be inferred from the context:

```
func bar<T>() -> [T] {
    return [T]()
}

let val1 = bar() as [Int] // or:
let val2 : [Int] = bar()
```

(I cannot answer the other questions.)

Comment: Okay, but if my function would return a `(T,[(T,T[T])])` (I doubt a good underlying design) for example I would have to retype the entire type with `Int` in every `T`-place?

Comment: @luk2302: The compiler must *somehow* infer the type from the context. If you pass `bar()` as an argument to a function taking an array parameter then it should work as well. – Perhaps there comes a better answer, but that's what I figured out.

Comment: yes, I know it needs to somehow get the type, I am basically confused as to why explicitly specifying it does not work - but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

The language doesn't allow you to explicitly specialize the function. I don't know why they implemented it that way. You're more likely to get an answer to that question on the swift-users mailing list.

The typical way to fix this is to make the function take the type as an argument:

```
func bar<T>(_: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return [T]()
}

bar(Int.self)
// Result: [], with type Array<Int>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the `Int.self`-solution. I will maybe make my first contribution / post on the mailing list as opposed to only reading it.