# Swift Generic Type Inference

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols, inference

So I was wondering if any one could explain the rational behind this error or an explanation of what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to create a generic function which takes a protocol constrained type which has a static method on it called solve.

But for some reason even though it resolves the constraint fine in Xcode the compiler throws a hissy.

Is there any reason it shouldn't be able to infer a type which I am already specifying or is there a naive error in my code sample?

Edit: As it wasnt explicit enough

I know how to work around it, I was just curious for an explanation of why static members in interfaces/ protocols are problematic.

[image]

```
protocol NodeSolver {
    static func solve(_ nodes: [Node]) -> [Node]
}

func findPath<T: NodeSolver>(nodes: [Node]) -> [Node]  {        
        return T.solve(nodes)
    }
```

Comment: You may enjoy this mind-boggling QA .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240091

Comment: @luk2302 I am specifying the type as NodeSolver (see: <T: NodeSolver>)

Comment: @luk2302 so is the answer that the class has to be static?

I dont get why the compiler wouldnt be able to infer the type.

 I am calling static members on a type. All it should need is the type information. Which I am handing to it in the generic type arguments

Comment: @SacredGeometry I deleted my comments, I did not see your reference to the method being static.

Comment: @luk2303 haha now you see my confusion right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you want `findPath` to be a method strongly connected to the *type* that conforms to `NodeSolver`, but wont use any instance of this concrete `NodeSolver` type in the `findPath` method itself, you might want to consider simply adding the general `findPath` method as a type method available by a default implementation for all types conforming to `NodeSolver`.

E.g.:

```
struct Node {}

protocol NodeSolver {
    static func solve(_ nodes: [Node]) -> [Node]
    static func findPath(nodes: [Node]) -> [Node]
}

extension NodeSolver {
    static func findPath(nodes: [Node]) -> [Node]  {
        // hopefully some more logic ...
        return Self.solve(nodes)
    }
}

struct MyNodeSolver: NodeSolver {
    // dummy solver
    static func solve(_ nodes: [Node]) -> [Node] {
        return nodes
    }
}

let myNodes = [Node(), Node()]

// make use of the default implementation of `findPath` available
// to all types conforming to 'NodeSolver': this method itself
// make use of the concrete type-specific implementation of 'solve'
// in the types conforming to 'NodeSolver'.
let dummyPath = MyNodeSolver.findPath(nodes: myNodes)
```

---

> I am handing a constrained type in the protocol I am specifying. And
>   the actual type in the method call.
>
> ```
> findPath<NodeSolver1>(nodes)
> findPath<NodeSolver2>(nodes)
> ```

Another workaround, possible closer to what you're trying to achieve, is to wrap the generic function into a generic type (say, `struct`) which holds a non-generic function `findPath` w.r.t. concrete versions of the generic type. If viewing the wrapped `findPath` from a viewpoint external to the owning type, the functions is generic w.r.t. the generic typeholder of the owning type.

E.g.:

```
struct Node {}

protocol NodeSolver {
    static func solve(_ nodes: [Node]) -> [Node]
}

struct NodeSolverA: NodeSolver {
    static func solve(_ nodes: [Node]) -> [Node] {
        return nodes
    }
}

struct NodeSolverB: NodeSolver {
    static func solve(_ nodes: [Node]) -> [Node] {
        return nodes.reversed()
    }
}

// instead of a generic function, wrap a concrete function
// in a generic type
struct AnyNodeSolver<T: NodeSolver> {
    static func findPath(nodes: [Node]) -> [Node]  {
        return T.solve(nodes)
    }
}

let myNodes = [Node(), Node()]

let dummyPathA = AnyNodeSolver<NodeSolverA>.findPath(nodes: myNodes)
let dummyPathB = AnyNodeSolver<NodeSolverB>.findPath(nodes: myNodes)
```

Comment: Incidentally I know how to work around it, I was just curious for an explanation of why static members in interfaces/ protocols are problematic. I will edit the question to include this comment as I dont think that bit was explicit enough.

Comment: @SacredGeometry ah, after you edit I realize this doesn't answer your question at all. I'll leave it, none the less, in case a reader is interested in one possible workaround (where the other answers shows workaround for including the generic type as an additional argument in the generic function's declaration.

Comment: @SacredGeometry I updated the answer with another "workaround" that might not have crossed your mind: this is one approach to handle `findPath` as if it were a generic function, but without explictly needing to include the generic type in the parameter list of the function (since the generic type is in fact owned by the generic wrapper that owns the actually non-generic function `findPath`).

Comment: Thank you for your time. Again its more a theoretical curiosity than an implementation problem. 

I am just curious how compilers deal with generics. 

I realise that there is no way to discern what implementation its using if you pass in the protocol as the generic type param. but...


for example: If, hypothetically, a class constraint existed in swift. 

What other information would the compiler need to differentiate between the types handed to it then the type param in the generics

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type of `T` in the function signature.

```
func findPath<T: NodeSolver>(nodes: [Node], ofType type: T.Type) -> [Node]  {        
    return T.solve(nodes)
}
```

Comment: I figured :) That is after all what the error states.

What I am asking is. Then what is the point of the generic? If you have to specify it twice?

Comment: Just incase it wasnt clear (as its happened once).

The function is static. The compiler shouldn't need an instance, just the type  to resolve it.

Comment: That's why you are not passing an instance but a type. You have to tell the compiler which type to use

Comment: Ok I will try this from a different angle. Is there a class constraint in swift?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

If so then it would have to be an implementation and not the protocol so it would need to be what I passed to it

Answer (score 1):

*If* you define a generic type you must enable the compiler to somehow infer the actual type. Currently there would be no way to achieve that. How would you make the two calls to that method with different `NodeSolver`s?

Yannick wrote an answer for specifying the type - you ask "Then what is the point of the generic? If you have to specify it twice?" - you do not have to. General example:

```
protocol P {
    static func solve(argument : String)
}

class P1 : P {
    class func solve(argument : String) {
        print("first")
    }
}

class P2 : P {
    class func solve(argument : String) {
        print("second")
    }
}


func doSome(argument : String, a : P.Type) {
    a.solve(argument: argument)
}

doSome(argument: "", a: P1.self) // prints "first"
doSome(argument: "", a: P2.self) // prints "second"
```

In your case:

```
func findPath(nodes: [Node], solver: NodeSolver.Type) -> [Node]  {        
    return solver.solve(nodes)
}
```

Comment: I am handing a consdtrained type in the protocol I am specifying. And the actual type in the method call. 

Normally languages restrict static members in interfaces I was excited to see that Swift didnt but then it didnt allow for this, and I am just curious what the technical blocker is for the compiler in inferring a type I am constraining and handing to it at compile time.

Regardless, I know lots of ways around this problem, (I am going to just pass it a delegate)

I am just trying to figure out what the actual hard problem is here.

Comment: @SacredGeometry please show how you would call *your* method `findPath` with two different `NodeSolver` implementations. There simply is not way - there cannot be any inferring, there is absolutely no information for the compiler to infer anything. Please show a little bit more context.

Comment: findPath<NodeSolver1>(nodes);       
findPath<NodeSolver2>(nodes);

Comment: both are classes that implement the NodeSolver protocol/ interface

Comment: @SacredGeometry you are not allowed to explicitly specify the type constraint when calling a method.

Comment: I am lost, isnt that what you are doing when you specify the type arguments? i.e. <MyType>

Comment: @SacredGeometry no - when calling a method you never specify the generic type, you always let the compiler infer it - when trying your ways of calling the method the compiler tells you "cannot explicitly specialize a generic function" and "while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket" - it simply is not supported ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372383/explicitly-specify-generic-type-constraint-when-calling-function )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136617/discussion-between-sacredgeometry-and-luk2302).