# Generic types error : Cannot explicitly specialise a generic type

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, generics, swift3, protocols

I'm trying to create a generic function in `RequestManager` that convert the received JSON from server to the specified type through the `ServiceManager`. This is my code:

**RequestManager:**

```
typealias ResultResponseManager  = (_ data: AnyObject?, _ error: ErrorPortage?) -> Void
typealias SuccessResponseManager = (_ success: Bool, _ error: ErrorPortage?) -> Void
typealias objectBlock<T:GenericModel> = (_ object: T?, _ error: ErrorPortage?) -> Void

extension RequestManager {

    static func getObject<T: GenericModel>(endpoint: String, completionBlock: objectBlock<T>? = nil){

        RequestHelper(url: "\(getAPIURL())\(endpoint))")
            .performJSONLaunchRequest { (result, error) in

                if let result = result as? NSDictionary,
                    error == nil {
                    let object = T(dic: result)
                    completionBlock?(object, nil)
                }
                else {
                    completionBlock?(nil, error)
                }
        }
    }


}
```

**ServiceManger:**

```
typealias ObjectResult =  (GenericModel?, ErrorPortage?) -> Void
typealias ObjectsResult =  ([GenericModel]?, ErrorPortage?) -> Void

extension ServiceManager {

    static func getUser(_ id: Int? = nil, _ completion: ObjectResult? = nil) {

        guard let userId: Int = id ?? UserManager.shared.userId else {

            return
        }

        RequestManager.getObject<User>(endpoint: "users/\(userId)") { (user, error) in
            if user = user {

                //update userdefault
                if userId == UserManager.shared.userId {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(result, forKey: "currentUser")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line `RequestManager.getObject<User> ...` I'm getting this error:

> Cannot explicitly specialise a generic type

So what did I miss here?

> The problem was solved thanks to luk2302

**Update**
Any idea how to improve this code maybe or make it more clean!
NB: This is not an issue it's just about good programming habits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/35372990/2442804 - you are not allowed to specify the type constraint "by hand". You have to make the compiler infer it. Do that via:

```
RequestManager.getObject(endpoint: "users/\(userId)") { (user : User?, error) in 
    // ... your normal code
```

Comment: Thank you :) could you check my update (it's just about having clean code and maybe to better organise my code)

Comment: @Chlebta I would go for an enum with associated values for the `error` and the `success` case. That way you have a compiler-enforced way to either receive error information or on actual object. There are a couple of post regarding this around on SO (cannot find them right now), going into more detail is too much for the comment section. Apart from the enum I think your code is fine.